# Tkinter button not changing global variable

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I have started learning python gui.Button function call doesn't update the global variable. Currently I am facing problem in below code.

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

root.title("learning")

s=""

def change() :

    global str
    str="program"

button1=Button(root,text="Click me", command=change).pack()

print(s)

root.mainloop()
```

The value of `str` does not update.

s=""

def change():

```
global s

s="program"
```

change()

print(s)

the value of s here gets printed program whereas using tkinter the value is blank.

Comment: `str` is a keyword in python. Keywords cannot be used as variable names. Change it to something else

Comment: changing variable name did not solve the problem. The value still does not change

Comment: a="hi" def check() : global a a="hello" check() print(a)  hello gets printed here but using tkinter button the value does not update

Comment: Ive added a quite detailed answer, do let me know

Comment: the function call using button is not updating the global variable whereas the direct call to the function updates it. why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()  
root.title("learning")    
x=""

def change() :   
    global x
    x="program"
    print(x)

def prt():
    global x
    print(x)

Button(root,text="Click me", command=change).pack()
Button(root,text="Print x", command=prt).pack()

root.mainloop()     
print(x)
```

Try to do this:

- Click 'Print x' first - This should print an empty space
- Then click on `Click Me` - `x` changes to *program*
- And then again click on 'Print x' - this should print *program*

Another error - `button1` is `None` as you have used `.pack` on the same line. So if you want to use `button1` in your code ahead, use it as:

```
button1 = Button(root, text='Click me', command=change)
button1.pack()
```

Comment: I have to use the variable in later part of code. My purpose is to use the variable not just print it and also can you explain  why the value is correct in the function but not outside the function

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from tkinter import *
    
    def change():
        global str
        str="program"
        print(str) # print function should be placed here
    
    root=Tk()
    root.title("learning")
    root.geometry("300x300")
    str=""
    button1=Button(root,text="Click me", command=change).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

when the button is clicked, immediately the function change() will be called so, the print function should be placed in change()